# dar formato a json con php

Tags: php

Buenas tardes tengo un array llenado desde una tabla de base  de datos denominado objeto, el mismo que convierto a json pero lo necesito en el siguiente formato, pero no logro conseguirlo:

```
formato = {"APORTE CLUB":"2.00"},{"TASA REGULATORIA":"0.50"}
```

Pero no he tenido éxito solo consigo esto

```
formato = [{"APORTE CLUB":"2.00"},{"TASA REGULATORIA":"0.50"}]
```

No necesito los corchetes ya que le formato es {"campo":valor}, he utilizado el siguiente código pero no puedo entender que hago mal.

```php
$sql = "consulta sql a la base dedatos;
$resp = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$resp->execute();
$resultado = $resp->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$objeto=array();
foreach ($resultado as $fila) 
{     
    $row = array(trim($fila['DESCRIP']) => $fila['SUBTOTAL']);               
    array_push($objeto, $row);            
}
echo json_encode($objeto);
```

Comment: `$objeto=array();` y luego `array_push($objeto, $row);` Obvio que va a obtener un array y dentro los array asociativos de cada registro. Por otro lado, no se entiende bien la pregunta, el formato obtenido y el deseado ¿no son el mismo, solo que sin los corchetes de array? ¿No será que lo que quieres es: `{"APORTE CLUB":"2.00", "TASA REGULATORIA":"0.50", ...}`?

Comment: exacto solo los corchetes están demás, debo quitar los corchetes del principio y final

Comment: @EdwinMisericordia, si sacas los corchetes, el resultado no sería un `JSON` válido. No estaría entendiendo porque necesitas sacarlos.

Comment: ese es el formato que piden para enviar a través servicios SOAP, consumo de servicios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo necesitas sacar los corchetes, podes utilizar [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) así:

```php
//... código anterior
echo substr(json_encode($objeto), 1, -1);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/3d5ef)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Este es el típico problema de cuando se quiere re-inventar la rueda.

Te comunico que puedes prescindir de casi todo lo que usas aquí si usas las herramientas adecuadas.

Veamos:

```
$sql = "SELECT DESCRIP, SUBTOTAL FROM ... COMPLETA TU CONSULTA";
$resp = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$resp->execute();
$resultado = $resp->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Al usar `fetchAll()` junto con `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` como forma de asociación, tendrás tu contenido listo para emitirlo como un json sin más historia.

Si esperas demasiadas filas el uso de `fetchAll()` puede dar problemas de memoria. En ese caso, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$sql = "SELECT DESCRIP, SUBTOTAL FROM ... COMPLETA TU CONSULTA";
$resp = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$resp->execute();
$object=array();
while ($row = $resp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $object[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($object);
```

Comment: El problema con tu respuesta es que el valor de `DESCRIP` es la clave y el valor de `SUBTOTAL` es el valor. Así como esta no vas a obtener el resultado esperado. Tampoco se quitan los corchetes al imprimir.

Comment: @Marcos no tendría sentido poner como clave de un json un valor dinámico, todas las claves deben llamarse igual, sería como querer cambiar la propiedad nombre o apellido por otra cosa. Los corchetes tampoco hay que quitarlos, representan un array de objetos. Creo que el problema principal aquí es de comprensión sobre cómo funcionan las cosas.

Comment: Es que eso no es lo que el OP busca. Te diría que releas la pregunta, porque estás dando una respuesta basándote en lo que vos crees que es lo correcto y no se ajusta al formato esperado en la pregunta.

Comment: @Marcos si no entendí mal, OP dice querer un formato `{"campo":valor}` y habla también de querer un JSON que tendría un conjunto de objetos, pero sin los corchetes, pero eso NO es posible, pues NO sería realmente un JSON válido. Con mi respuesta simplemente intento corregir ciertas concepciones que me parecen erróneas: si OP quiere un conjunto de objetos pero sin corchetes no validaría nunca y si quiere un json cuyos campos en cada objeto no son siempre los mismos (nombre, apellido, etc) eso resultará en algo totalmente inutilizable.

Comment: Si te fijas en detalle vas a ver que cada objeto es distinto, ya que como explique las claves varían. Con respecto a que sacar los cochetes deja de ser un JSON válido, ya esta aceptado y aún así lo necesita así ya que es para ser enviado a un servicio externo. Ojo, yo no digo que tu respuesta carece de sentido, solo quiero señalar que el resultado no se ajusta al esperado.

Comment: @Marcos yo sigo pensando que el principal problema aquí es un error de comprensión, más aún si OP requiere esta respuesta para consumirla en otro contexto. Es más, creo que lo que aquí ocurre es algo gravísimo desde el punto de vista de modelo de datos: **se tratan valores como si fueran campos o propiedades**. Creo sinceramente que OP quiere esto por desconocimiento de cómo funcionan las cosas. Es lo que yo pienso, que no significa que tenga razón. Ya OP verá si le conviene lo sugerido o no y si estoy equivocado en algo OP puede también señalarlo en un comentario o editando su pregunta.

Comment: Si tomamos como premisa la pregunta y el resultado esperado, puedo decir que tu respuesta no es válida. Hasta donde se el OP busca enviar información a un servicio que require la info en cierto formato y eso es todo. Si tu respuesta diera una solución al problema real y después adicionara info de como crees vos que debería ser, ahí estaria de acuerdo en que si es válida.

Comment: @Marcos a mi juicio, *responder* puede significar en ciertos casos ayudar a rectificar errores detectados en otra fase del programa, en el diseño, en la lógica, en las herramientas usadas, en el modelo de datos. Más de una vez ha ocurrido que el problema real está en otra parte y creo que este podría ser el caso. Me gustaría saber por ejemplo qué hace OP en el destino para rearmar su array de objetos, ¿quizá recurre de nuevo a código para crear un array de objetos, después de haberlo destruido quitando los corchetes? Jamás SOAP te va a pedir una respuesta que no tenga sentido ...

Comment: ... y esto es lo que parece decir OP en uno de los comentarios, que SOAP le pide un array de JSON que NO es realmente un array de JSON, porque le ha quitado los corchetes. ¿De qué modo SOAP va a hacer esto entendible y consumible en el destino? ¿De qué modo lo va a incorporar a un modelo, cuando al parecer se usan valores como campos o propiedades? Como ya dije, es mi opinión, pero yo veo un problema grave aquí, aunque no tengo por qué tener la razón, simplemente expongo lo que intuyo viendo la pregunta y el código.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142364/discussion-between-marcos-and-a-cedano).